# Changing radiobutton background in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice in android?

Tags: android

In `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` has below layout-

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
/>
```

How we can change `radiobutton` background in that view. It is green by default and I want to have my own image instead of green radio button. I think we have make changes in `attr` of `listChoiceIndicatorSingle`. But I am not able to find that listChoiceIndicatorSingle any where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK done. I was able to locate style and selector file for radio button in platofrom folder inside sdk. Thanks for your time.